# can you share a static image in react share?

Tags: image, react-scripts

```
<WhatsappShareButton
    url={url}
    className="icon"
    >
        <WhatsappIcon size={50} round/>
     <Typography>Whatsapp</Typography>   
    </WhatsappShareButton>
```

I am useing react-share package

i have a static image next to this componennt, how can i sent the pic?

I try to use meta data, or send my website icon, or put it in the url or title, none of this work!
what can i do to send a static image, statin in my code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.